# incorrect syntax near '=' error on sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using just creating PROCEDURE and calling the procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ActiveUser @UserID int
AS
SELECT * FROM UserInfo WHERE UserID = @UserID;

EXEC ActiveUser UserID = "1"
```

But get this error

> Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: you missed a `@` on the input parameter in `EXEC ActiveUser @UserID = '1'` and also use single quote for string

Comment: or you could just run  `EXEC ActiveUser '1'`

Comment: just noticed that your parameter is actually an integer. Don't use the single quote around the integer value `EXEC ActiveUser @UserID = 1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually correct syntax is

If you direct calling this:

```
    EXEC ActiveUser 1
```

or

```
    EXEC ActiveUser @Userid = 1
```

Or if by passing parameter

```
  declare @par int = 1
  EXEC ActiveUser @par
```

Comment: ... Or `EXEC ActiveUser @UserID = 1;` This is useful when executing a procedure with many parameters - it makes the `exec` code much more readable.